# windows service: get each users' %APPDATA% variable

Tags: c, winapi, windows-services, environment-variables, setuid

My application runs as service and at some point it needs to loop through all existing user accounts on the system(I figured this can be done with `NetUserEnum()`) and try accessing a certain file under each of found users' %APPDATA% path. Problem is I have no idea how to get that user-specific path (%APPDATA%).

Since application runs as service (SYSTEM), I cannot use environment or `SHGetFolderPath()`. Initially I thought I could make a use of `LogonUser()` but it always throws error 1326 at me, no matter if I run my application test code under user, admin or SYSTEM. (winxp as test platform). If there is a way to obtain user login handle, I can use that in `SHGetFolderPath()` or `ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser()` APIs, is that correct?

So, the code I tried so far with LogonUser() is about the following(yes, username IS correct):

```
LogonUser(
    pw->usri1_name,
    L".",
    NULL,
    LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
    &authtoken
)
```

It probably wants my password but there is no way I know that on customer machine. All the APIs I found with quick search rely on HANDLE from LogonUser() which I apparently cannot have...

Any non-tricky and tricky ideas welcome!

Comment: %appdata% seems to differ for various system releases and probably, languages too, which i cannot test, so i cannot simply bruteforce that. i can, but at least i hope it wont come down to that? /facepalm/

Comment: Error 1326 is `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE` (Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password). You are not supplying any password, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution and conclusions so far.

You cannot use `LogonUser()` properly.

Instead, your options come to **bruteforcing** the path after user homedir(which you still obtain via any preferred method, my suggested is `NetUserEnum()`), based on one of the following:

- `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)`
- reg key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

If you know of any other method please comment.

Answer (score 0):

> service or application run as "local system" to get special folder

this example we get **CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY**,  work well at xp, win7(32,64)

```
DWORD ServiceGetDesktopDirectory(LPWSTR lpUserName, LPWSTR lpPassword,
    LPWSTR lpDomain, LPWSTR lpBuffer)
{

HANDLE hToken;
BOOL bRet;
bRet = LogonUserW(lpUserName,
                 lpDomain,
                 lpPassword,
                 LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                 LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                 &hToken);
if (!bRet) {
    error("LogonUser failed, gle = %lu", GetLastError());
    return FILE_ERR_INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD;
}


NET_API_STATUS ntStatus;
USER_INFO_4 *pUserInfo;
ntStatus = NetUserGetInfo((LPCWSTR)lpDomain,
                          (LPCWSTR)lpUserName,
                          4,
                          (BYTE**)&pUserInfo);
if (ntStatus != NERR_Success) {
    error("NetUserGetInfo failed, ntStatus 0X%x", ntStatus);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return FILE_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR;
}

PROFILEINFOW profile;
memset(&profile, 0, sizeof(PROFILEINFOW));
profile.dwSize = sizeof(PROFILEINFOW);
profile.lpUserName = lpUserName;
profile.lpProfilePath = pUserInfo->usri4_profile;
bRet = LoadUserProfileW(hToken, &profile);
if (!bRet) {
    error("LoadUserProfile failed, gle = %lu", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    NetApiBufferFree(pUserInfo);
    return FILE_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR;
}


HRESULT hr;
hr = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL,
              CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
              hToken,
              0,
              lpBuffer);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    error("SHGetFolderPath failed, hr 0X%x", hr);
    NetApiBufferFree(pUserInfo);
    UnloadUserProfile(hToken, profile.hProfile);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return FILE_ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR;
}

NetApiBufferFree(pUserInfo);
UnloadUserProfile(hToken, profile.hProfile);
CloseHandle(hToken);
return FILE_ERR_OK;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve each login session's token.

Also look at [`LoadUserProfile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is needed for a service to access the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key for a specific user.  The user must be logged in, either interactively or programmably, or impersonated in order to get the required user token.

Another option is to enumerate the `HKEY_USERS` key to retrieve the SIDs of the user accounts, then use [`LookupAccountSid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve their usernames, and then format the AppData paths manually based on OS version.  Not as flexible, but less dependant on user-specific registry data.

Otherwise, forget trying to write to user-specific folders from a service.  Write to common shared folders instead, like `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` and `FOLDERID_ProgramData`.

Comment: it works only for logged in users, moreover, for RDP-logged in. i need to collect all existing users' %APPDATA% so this approach does not work. LoadUserProfile() asks me a HANDLE which i do not have either.

Comment: You have to load the user's profile in order to access that user's registry data. The user needs to be logged in or impersonated in order to get that user's token in order to load that user's profile.  That is the HANDLE that LoadUserProfile() is expecting.

Comment: any more hints on how do i load profiles of not logged in users? since it is service it may be started way earlier than any user will log into system, so there are no sessions available.

Comment: thanks for edit, but on my winxp i have two other users beside me yet i only see my own key in HKU, be it from SYSTEM(in radmin telnet, reg query HKEY_USERS) or regedit under admin user. anyway it still does come down to bruteforcing appdata folder name? omg